# SwiftUI animation rotation glitch @ 360/0 degree marker

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

So I have a view that rotates according to a specific degree that is set by the direction the device is pointed in. The problem is when you go from 359.99 to 0.01 degree rotation (which is the smallest difference in actuality, the view chooses to rotate all the way from 360 down to 0, instead of just wrapping around. This causes problems with the animation because it makes the view spin 359 degrees back to the 0 position instead of just clicking into the 0 degree position from 359. I've tried setting animation to nil between 359-360 and 0-1 but if you move the device fast enough, you still see this bad animation. Any suggestions?

```
Image("arrow")
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: deviceHeading))
    .animation(.easeOut)
```

https://youtu.be/MzpI6THHS8U

As you can see, right in that position, it rotates fully around instead of just doing a change of taking the short path to the new position.

Comment: Instead of rotating from 359.99 to 0.01, rotate to 360.01 -- you can use values larger than 360. For each iteration, you'd want/need to figure out if you should keep the current multiple of 360 as an underlying value or step up to the next multiple.

Comment: @jnpdx My problem is it's a formula that won't allow the value to go above 360, otherwise yeah I could do that--is there a way of animating the shortest path to the next state instead of doing the longest?

Comment: Maybe someone will chime in with something. If not, even you are beholden to a formula that won't let it go about 360, that shouldn't prevent you from putting in an intermediate step/variable that tests to see if the new value needs to be converted to the +360 scale.

Comment: @jnpdx Fair enough, I could try to rethink the I'm setting up the formula, but I was wondering if maybe I could UIView.animate and CGAffineTransform but it would be cool if there was an easier solution

Comment: @nickcoding2: There is a big deference between 0 and 360 or even 1 and 361 for xCode, for us it is the same! It can be solved with a simple mathematical if statement.

Comment: @nickcoding2 Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 17 / watchOS 10 / tvOS 17 / macOS 14 / Mac Catalyst 17 / VisionOS 1

In SwiftUI `withAnimation` has a completionHandler now.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:completioncriteria:_:completion:)

Using that you could temporarily calculate the new rotation degrees based on the shortest route of the animation. And then once the animation completes, you correct the rotation degrees to the actual value of the device heading.

Here is a code snippet that I think should work (not yet tested):

```
@available(watchOS 10.0, *)
struct CompassArrowView: View {
    var deviceHeading: CLLocationDegrees
    @State private var rotationDegrees: CLLocationDegrees = .zero

    init(deviceHeading: CLLocationDegrees) {
        self.deviceHeading = deviceHeading
        self.rotationDegrees = deviceHeading
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image("arrow")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationDegrees))
            .onChange(of: deviceHeading) { oldValue, newValue in
                if abs(newValue - oldValue) > 180.0 {
                    if newValue < oldValue {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) { [self] in
                            rotationDegrees = newValue + 360
                        } completion: { [self] in
                            rotationDegrees = rotationDegrees - 360
                        }
                    } else {
                        rotationDegrees = oldValue + 360
                        withAnimation(.easeOut) { [self] in
                            rotationDegrees = newValue
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    withAnimation(.easeOut) { [self] in
                        rotationDegrees = newValue
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```